# replace tags while giving a list of tags at the begining

Tags: xslt, xpath

my xml input is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1255"?>
<ns0:PatMedData xmlns="http://Maccabi.Hospitals.Integration"  xmlns:ns0="http://Maccabi.Hospitals.Integration">
<MessageId>AS80000000000456</MessageId>
</ns0:PatMedData>
```

I cant change the xml scheme, the problem is that the root element has 
xmlns="http://Maccabi.Hospitals.Integration"  and xmlns:ns0="http://Maccabi.Hospitals.Integration" 
this causes weird problems

i tried this xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//*[local-name() = 'MessageId']">
<xsl:element name="brlName"/> 
<xsl:text>BBB</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the reuslt is:

```
  <brlName xmlns="">BBB</brlName>
```

how do i get rid of the xmlns=""???

thanks...

Comment: In what namespace is "brlName" supposed to be in?

Answer (score 1):

The result you are actually getting is this... (Although I suspect you did mean to wrap **BBB** in the **xsl:element** tag)

```
<ns0:PatMedData xmlns="http://Maccabi.Hospitals.Integration"
                xmlns:ns0="http://Maccabi.Hospitals.Integration">
    <brlName xmlns=""/>BBB
</ns0:PatMedData>
```

The confusion lies in the fact the root element has two namespace declarations. Both have the same URI, but one is declared as the default namespace, and the other bound to prefix **ns0**. When you are outputting **brlName** you are outputting it with no namespace, but because the root element has a default namespace declared, it is output as `<brlName xmlns=""/>` to show it has no namespace, otherwise it would be part of the existing namespace declared.

What you haven't said is whether the new **brlName** is meant to be in the same namespace, or whether is should not be in any namespace.

If you want **brlName** to be part of the same namespace as the root element, change your **xsl:element** to this

```
<xsl:element name="brlName" namespace="{namespace-uri()}" />
```

This will output the following:

```
<ns0:PatMedData xmlns="http://Maccabi.Hospitals.Integration"
                xmlns:ns0="http://Maccabi.Hospitals.Integration">
    <brlName/>BBB
</ns0:PatMedData>
```

But, if you wanted **brlName** not to be in any namespace, but really didn't like the `xlmns=''` being present you could write a template to remove the default namespace from the root. To do this, instead of changing the **xsl:element**, try adding this extra template to the XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

This should yield the following:

```
<ns0:PatMedData xmlns:ns0="http://Maccabi.Hospitals.Integration">
   <brlName/>BBB
</ns0:PatMedData>
```

It is important to re-iterate the two solutions are not the same. The first solution leaves **brlName** in the same namespace as the root **PatMedData** element. In the second, **brlName** is not in a namespace at all.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<xsl:element name="brlName"/> 
<xsl:text>BBB</xsl:text>
```

To:

```
<xsl:element name="brlName" namespace="http://Maccabi.Hospitals.Integration">
    <xsl:text>BBB</xsl:text>
</xsl:element>
```

But if you are going to add some element you better declare the namespace

Comment: first of all thanks.how can i remove the defult namespace and leave the one with the parameter by xslt?